Why dispatching event from volt component is not catched in other component?
In laravel 11 / livewire 3.5 / mary-ui 1.40.3 app I need to catch time when user logged into the system
so I modified resources/views/livewire/pages/auth/login.blade.php component and added event "userAuthenticated" dispatching:
<?php

use App\Livewire\Forms\LoginForm;
use App\Livewire\Personal\UserLoggedTime;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Livewire\Attributes\Layout;
use Livewire\Volt\Component;

new #[Layout('layouts.guest')] class extends Component {
    public LoginForm $form;

    /**
     * Handle an incoming authentication request.
     */
    public function login(): void
    {
        $this->validate();

        $this->form->authenticate();

        Session::regenerate();
        $this->dispatch('userAuthenticated');//->to(UserLoggedTime::class);
        \Log::info(' -99 userAuthenticated AFTER::');

        $this->redirectIntended(default: route('admin.dashboard', absolute: false), navigate: true);
    }
}; ?>

and custom component catching this event :
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Personal;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Livewire\Component;

class UserLoggedTime extends Component
{
    public $loggedTime = null;
    public function render()
    {
        $minuteDiff = !empty($this->loggedTime) ? $this->loggedTime->diffInMinutes(Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", date("Y-m-d H:i:00"))) : null;
        return view('livewire.personal.user-logged-time', ['loggedTime' => $this->loggedTime, 'minuteDiff' => $minuteDiff]);
    }

    #[On('userAuthenticated')]
    public function userAuthenticated()
    {
        dd('userAuthenticated');
        $this->loggedTime =  Carbon::now(\config('app.timezone'));

        \Log::info(varDump($this->loggedTime, ' -1 userAuthenticated $this->loggedTime::'));
    }
}

After user logged I see text  -99 userAuthenticated AFTER:: in log file, but the app is not dies at dd(\'userAuthenticated\'); line.
Uncommenting ->to(UserLoggedTime::class) ->to(UserLoggedTime::class) did not help in anyway - userAuthenticated is not called.
I suppose that dispatching from volt component works the same and must be catched in UserLoggedTime Component. Why it is not triggered ?
